# How to cast int to boolean when doing SQL transform in Apache Beam

Tags: java, sql, apache-beam, apache-calcite, beam-sql

I'm trying to do a SQL transform with Apache Beam using Calcite SQL syntax. I'm doing an int to boolean cast. My sql looks like this:

```
,CASE WHEN cast(IsService as BOOLEAN) THEN CASE WHEN IsEligible THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE NULL END AS Reported
```

Where IsService is an indicator int and IsEligible is a boolean.

According to the [documentation](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html#implicit-type-conversion) an explicit cast from int to boolean is fine.
However, I get the below error when I run the pipeline:

```
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Cast function cannot convert value of type INTEGER to type BOOLEAN
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting the error?

Comment: What's the underlying database?

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm reading from a Kafka topic

Comment: why don't just use `IsService = [int]` , is cast absolute needed here?

Comment: @T.Peter you're right, it would work, but my sql is being auto generated somewhere else and changing that is a pain in the butt. Was just curious as to why i was getting the error

Comment: Taking a look. Beam is on a pretty old version of Calcite, so that might be it. I'm going to add another answer to solve your problem, though.

Comment: Oh, also: what version of Beam?

Comment: @KennKnowles I'm using Beam version 1.24, but also tried with the latest 1.27 with the same result. However, it looks like it's using version 1.20 of Calcite, which is almost 2 years old..

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem immediately, you could use `IsService > 0` instead of `CAST`. In my opinion, it is even more clear what the conversion is. I am not a fan of relying on "falsey" values.

Comment: using `> 0` would solve the problem, but that requires changes in the sql which is auto generated and it's a big hassle